# Are there any latching transistors without relays?

Tags: transistors

I am currently working on a diy 4 bit computer but I have ran In to a problem. In order to create bytes that can be changed by my processor I need to have some kind of transistor that latches to true as soon as it is given a signal (imagine a piston or actuator hitting a latching button any time a signal is sent). I don't own any relays and I would prefer to have this component in a IC form (if it exists) and I wouldn't mind buying them, but I'm just wondering if there is a way to make my own without relays.

Comment: is an scr what you are looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silicon_controlled_rectifier Although the double transistor equivalent circuit may be more useful when correctly configured.

Comment: What about "unlatching"? How do you envision that?

Comment: Cross coupled transistors can be latched or unlatched .Remember the RS latch taught bin most colledges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is called an [SR latch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#SR_latch). It's not a transistor - though it can be constructed from discrete transistors - and it's available in IC form, for example the [CD4043/CD4044](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1962418.pdf).

The latch has two input pins, (S)et and (R)eset. A high level on S turns the latch on, and a high level on R turns the latch off again.

More generally, if you're working on building your own processor, it's worth spending some more time reading about different types of latch and how they behave. D latches and registers in particular are likely to prove incredibly useful to you.

Latches are also frequently called Flipflops.

Comment: SR and D latches are also known as "flip-flops", which might be a better search term.

Comment: Yes, flip-flops indeed!! And they come in configurations of 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 16 per IC package -- sometimes even many many more. You can get them where they work individually or in parallel in the package. There are also a plethora of other combinations available as well including serial access, special interface access such as I2C or SPI, and connected at will such as inside FPGAs where some have 1000's of flip-flops.

Comment: @PeteBecker, but OP should also be aware that a D-latch and a D-flip-flop are not the same thing.

Comment: @ThePhoton - thanks. I didn't know that a D-latch and a D-flip-flop were different.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Flip-flops synchronize to a clock

Comment: When I learned it, we called them "flip flops" and "clocked flip flops"

Comment: I've looked at flip flops before but all I have found is integrated circuits, and no single components

Comment: @finlx They do exist in SMT, but why do you want a single flipflop? Any CPU is going to require a lot of them!

Answer (score 1):

Consider something like a [74HC74](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT74.pdf) flip-flop.

[image]

For this purpose you can ground the clock (CP) input and D input or use it for reset purposes.

The FF powers up in an indeterminate state. It can be reset to Q low by bringing RD low momentarily, or a low-to-high transition on CP with D held low.

Bringing SD low will cause Q to go high and it will stay high after SD goes high again.

If you prefer active-high inputs, there are 4000-series CMOS parts that are similar but with inverted inputs.

Comment: There used to be some SR latches in the 74HC series (like [74HC279](http://noel.feld.cvut.cz/hw/st/1937.pdf)), but thery're not made anymore, so indeed this seem a necessary substitution for high-speed CMOS. Actually Toshiba still makes those [on special order it seems](http://avnetexpress.avnet.com/store/em/EMController?action=products&catalogId=500201&storeId=500201&N=0&defaultCurrency=EUR&defaultRegion=EMEA&langId=-1&slnk=e&term=TC74HC279AP%2528F%2529&mfr=TOS&hrf=http%3A%2F%2Fad.icnara.com%2Fsf_all_total.jsp&r=EMEA&CMP=KNC-EMEA_FindChips_inventoryfeed_VSE&c=EUR).